# How can I add specific blackout dates in datepicker c# wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I'm using a Datepicker and I would like to add specific dates as blackout dates , the problem is that this property forces the add only with Calendar Range ,

Is there any possibility to add days without range ?

My example is to add only all Saturdays of all weeks of this year as blackout dates :

```
        DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2021, 01, 01);
        DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2021, 12, 31);
        int totalDays = (int)(d2 - d1).TotalDays;
        List<DateTime> dateStart = new List<DateTime>() { d1 };

        var result = dateStart.SelectMany(d => Enumerable.Range(0, totalDays)
                              .Select(days => d.AddDays(days))
                              .Where(x => x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday &&
                                          x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday));

        CalendarDateRange dr = new CalendarDateRange();
        dr.Start = result.First();
        dr.End = result.Last();
        datetime.BlackoutDates.Add(dr);
```

I would like to select all days except Saturday or Sunday ,

For example , for this month :

- 5,12,19,26 should not be acceptable ( Saturday )
- 6,13,20,27 should not be acceptable ( Sunday )

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: The range can even be one day. What is the obstacle to its application?

Comment: I would like to create a range with specific days ( maybe it calls range with the condition )  what you talk about is hardcoded and I can't type all days in range, I will give you an example, for example, I would like to select a range from 1 -> 5 , 1,2,3,4,5 but except 2 and 3 , so it will be 1,4,5. That what I needed a range but with except or with condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are asking if there is an easier way to a CalendarDateRange without passing in time. There is a constructor that takes in DateTime.

```
datetime.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(dateTime));
```

I provided a sample of code that will loop through a given year and add all Saturday's and Sunday's to the DatePicker's Blackout Dates

```
DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2021, 01, 01);
List<DateTime> dateStart = new List<DateTime>();

while (d1.Year == 2021)
{
    if ((d1.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) ||
        (d1.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday))
        dateStart.Add(d1);
    d1 = d1.AddDays(1);
}

foreach (DateTime dateTime in dateStart)
{
    datetime.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(dateTime));
}
```